# string argument without an encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, data-analysis

Can someone please tell why am I receiving the following error on python 3.  The following is the traceback:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-24-a81d4875414b> in <module>()
      7     filename = [("id"), ("name"), ("email"), ("amount"),("sent")]
      8     writer= csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames = fieldnames)
----> 9     writer.writeheader()
     10 
     11     for row in reader:
C:\Users\johsc_001\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ipykernel_py3\lib\csv.py in writeheader(self)
    142     def writeheader(self):
    143         header = dict(zip(self.fieldnames, self.fieldnames))
--> 144         self.writerow(header)
    145 
    146     def _dict_to_list(self, rowdict):
C:\Users\johsc_001\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ipykernel_py3\lib\csv.py in writerow(self, rowdict)
    153 
    154     def writerow(self, rowdict):
--> 155         return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
    156 
    157     def writerows(self, rowdicts):
C:\Users\johsc_001\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\ipykernel_py3\lib\tempfile.py in func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    481             @_functools.wraps(func)
    482             def func_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
--> 483                 return func(*args, **kwargs)
    484             # Avoid closing the file as long as the wrapper is alive,
    485             # see issue #18879.

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Here's the source code:

```
import csv
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile 
filename = 'appendpyt2.csv' 
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete= False) 
with open(filename, 'rb')as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader =csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    filename = ["id", "name", "email", "amount", "sent"]
    writer= csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames = ["id", "name", "email","amout", "sent"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        writer.writerow({
            "id": row["id"],
            "name": row["name"],
            "email":row["email"],
            "amout":"1234.56",
            "sent": ""
        })
```

Comment: it seems that the problem is opening the file as 'rb'. provide the stacktrace please to the quetion

Comment: Can you show the actual traceback?  BTW, this is not an [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It helps tremendously when you do provide one.

Comment: You tagged this with both 2.7 and 3-x.  Which are you using? Often string encoding issues differ between the two.

Comment: The first line isn't even valid Python.  All this code generates is syntax error.

Comment: correct the layout and syntax.

Comment: @ShmulikA I include the traceback in my code, When you get the chance please tell me what you think

Comment: @jszakmeister I am so sorry I am new to this I will be sure to  provide one next time and I just included the traceback in the post. Please tell me what you think when you get the chance.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes I know  I wanna know how to do it with both python versions it was point  essentially I am using them both. Please let me know what you think whenever you available. Thank you

Comment: @MarkTolonen Well the problem is not with the first line it's valid. it's a line to import something from a library in python, I don't know I am not sure but tempfile may not be a popular library.

Comment: @user3752995 What are you trying to do in that line?  Note: the line in the traceback is different than in the posted code!  In this case, if you're turning a string into bytes, then you need to specify which encoding to use (UTF-8, ASCII, UTF-16, Latin1, etc.).  The correct choice depends on you and what you are doing.  If you really need bytes, then I'd suggest using `"string".encode("utf-8")` as the way to get bytes from the string.  But it doesn't look like the line is serving a purpose right now, and, like I said earlier, it doesn't match your posted source code. :-(

Comment: @jszakmeister I am learning how to edit  a csv file? which line are you talking about specifically? One question if were to convert strings into byte will I need to that for the following line as well filename = ["id", "name", "email", "amount", "sent"]?

Comment: The first line is valid now that someone edited it, but `import shutil from tempfile` is not valid Python.

Comment: @user3752995 In your traceback, it's stopping on the `filename =` line (line number 7 in the traceback).  The `bytes("string")` that you using is invalid, you have to specify an encoding for strings.  Unfortunately, the **code you posted below the traceback doesn't match the traceback**, which is only making things more confusing.

Comment: @jszakmeister I am not sure why it's not matching this is the traceback I get from the code. Unless I tried to do something after the error and  forgot to run the code I am gonna  ran the code again an make sure the code in the post and the traceback are the samething

Comment: @jszakmeister I just made sure I got the correct traceback for the right code, when you can please take a look at it and tell me what you see.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I see  what  you meant, the code generate a type error now. What do you think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be from using Python 3, but using Python 2 requirements for opening `csv` files.  If using Python 3, CSV files should not be opened in binary mode, and the the newline parameter should be the empty string.  The temporary file defaults to binary mode as well, so I've overridden it.  I also used the following as an input file, deduced from the code since sample input wasn't provided.

**appendpyt2.csv:**

```
id,name,email
id1,name1,email1
id2,name2,email2
```

**Python 3 code:**

```
import csv
import shutil
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile 
filename = 'appendpyt2.csv' 
temp_file = NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+',newline='',delete= False) 
with open(filename,newline='') as csvfile, temp_file:
    reader =csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    filename = ["id", "name", "email", "amount", "sent"]
    writer= csv.DictWriter(temp_file, fieldnames = ["id", "name", "email","amount", "sent"])
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
        writer.writerow({
            "id": row["id"],
            "name": row["name"],
            "email":row["email"],
            "amount":"1234.56",
            "sent": ""
        })
```

**Temporary file output:**

```
id,name,email,amount,sent
id1,name1,email1,1234.56,
id2,name2,email2,1234.56,
```

Comment: Thank you very much